# Sharepoint Designer and sass

Tags: designer-workflow, branding, sharepoint-designer

I am working on Branding a Publishing Site on SharePoint Enterprise 2013 server and I am using SharePoint designer 2013 and I am looking for a way to use SASS to speed up my workflow because I am used to it and its great capabilities.

Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint is a web application and it recognized CSS style. Hence the complied `sass` files can be used in SharePoint.

If you use Visual Studio then you can install the [Compass extension](http://www.sharepoint13blog.com/sass-in-visual-studio-sharepoint/) to automate the process.

Else you need to compile the file using command and replace it in SharePoint using Designer or Browser.

Comment: I know that really what i dont know is how to use visual studio to edit publishing site instead of sharepoint designer ill look for that

Comment: Yes in Visual Studio you create a solution which can be deployed into SharePoint. In that solution you can define everything like master page, css and lot more. The good thing about this is you can apply this package to any environment and remove when its not used. In case of SharePoint Designer you are making the changes directly and there is no way to roll back.

Comment: Thats really great can you please refer to any online resource, search keyworks or tutorial ?

Comment: This will not be easy. To start you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231568.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bobgerman/archive/2011/01/31/packaging-master-pages-and-page-layouts-with-visual-studio-2010.aspx will help with master page and css.

Comment: I know about masterpages and ive already created the masterpage and styesheets and everything i just wanna know about the workflow

Comment: what you mean by workflow? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: About how to deploy visual studio solution that u just told about and be able to apply on diffirent environments plus also using that compasd extenstion to automate sass processing

Comment: Yes you can follow the hyperlinks I posted above. Just skip the portion of creating files etc..